# how do I get coordinates anywhere on a 3d object in c#, unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coordinates, clicking

So, I have a 3d object, and I am trying to get the x,y,z position when I click anywhere within the 3d object, but I have no idea how.

For example, if I were to click in the middle of the 3d object, it will give me coordinates (0,50,0). and if I click on the top left, it will say (0,0,0).

EDIT: I want to get the coordinate when I click anywhere on my 3d object relative to the object pivot point

Comment: Your question is very broad and unclear .. in general you can get the hit point via a `Physics.Raycast` in **world space**. If you than want to get the position relative to your object you can get it via `transform.InverseTransformPoint` ... however it will still be relative to your objects pivot point ... It is quite unclear how exactly the expected behavior would look like

Comment: EDIT: I want to get the coordinate when I click anywhere on my 3d object relative to the object pivot point

Answer (score 1):

you can do the following (assuming your object has a `MeshCollider` attached - or any other `Collider` but of course you will get the point on the collider not the mesh itself)

```
var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out var hit))
{
    var worldPoint = hit.point;
    var relativePoint = hit.transform.InverseTransformPoint(worldPoint);

    Debug.Log($"You have hit object {hit.gameObject} at position {relativePoint.ToString("G9")}");
}
```

See

- [`Camera.main`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-main.html)
- [`Camera.ScreenPointToRay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html)
- [`Physics.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html)
- [`RaycastHit.point`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-point.html)
- [`Transform.InverseTransformPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformPoint.html)